# Semantic JavaScript singleton with constructor

Tags: javascript, singleton

So I'd like to have a class called `client` which will be the base of a video game I'm writing in JavaScript.

`client` should be a class that there can only be one instance of, but its first creation should be set by myself at a specific event, like when the user clicks the "start" button.

I made myself a singleton class and I'm starting it unload just for testing:

```
// Singleton class for the client
var client = (function() {

  // Public methods
  var _this = {
    construct: function() {
      delete _this.construct;
      _this.director = new lime.Director(document.body, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); // Setup the rendering engine
    }
  }
  return _this;
})();

// Fire when dependencies are loaded
window.onload = client.construct;
```

**The problem:**

But I intend for this to be an open source project and on the last line `client.construct` seems to be a highly unusual convention. How can I write my singleton class so that it will be constructed with `new Client` and can never be constructed again?

Comment: this may help you:  http://web.archive.org/web/20130924134444/http://kaijaeger.com/articles/the-singleton-design-pattern-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly: are you sure you really want to do this? For most simple cases, you're probably better off not bothering with a `prototype` or using the `new` keyword at all, and instead just writing an object literal with the properties and methods you want - or creating an object with a one-off function if slightly more complicated construction logic is required. Simplicity is good.

I guess there are a couple of situations in which you might want to create a 'traditional' singleton in JavaScript, though - like to delay instantiation, or if you're using [classical inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) involving your singleton class's prototype.

In that case, you might want to try this approach, based upon bfavaretto's, in which the user of the class is expected to get a Client object by calling `Client.getSingletonInstance()` instead of `new Client()`, and the instantiation of a Client via `new` happens inside the `getSingletonInstance()` method.

```
var Client = (function() {
    // Our "private" instance
    var instance;

    // The constructor
    function Client() {

        // If it's being called again, throw an error
        if (typeof instance != "undefined") {
            throw new Error("Client can only be instantiated once.");
        }

        // initialize here

        // Keep a closured reference to the instance
        instance = this;
    }

    // Add public methods to Client.prototype
    Client.prototype.myPublic = function() {

    }

    Client.getSingletonInstance = function() {
        if (typeof instance == "undefined") {
            return new this();
        }
        else {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    // Return the constructor
    return Client;
})();


var c1 = Client.getSingletonInstance();
var c2 = Client.getSingletonInstance();

console.log(c1 == c2); // true
```

I prefer this way, because it seems to me that having the user of the class call `new` but not actually get a new object is misleading.

http://jsfiddle.net/hBvSZ/3/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same pattern you would use in a regular object-oriented language: store the instance in a "private" or "static" property (I'm quoting those terms because they don't precisely apply to JavaScript). In code, that would be something like this, using a "private" property to store the instance (a "static" property would be a property of the constructor):

```
var Client = (function() {
    // Our "private" instance
    var instance;

    // The constructor
    function Client() {

        // If it's being called again, return the singleton instance
        if(typeof instance != "undefined") return instance;

        // initialize here

        // Keep a closured reference to the instance
        instance = this;
    }

    // Add public methods to Client.prototype
    Client.prototype.myPublic = function() {

    }

    // Return the constructor
    return Client;
})();


var c1 = new Client();
var c2 = new Client();

console.log(c1 == c2); // true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hBvSZ/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var Client = (function ClientClass(){

  var instance;

  // Constructor
  function Client() {
    if (instance) throw 'Already instantiated';
    this.director = new lime.Director(...);
    instance = true;
  }

  Client.prototype = {
    // Public methods
  };

  return Client;

}());
```

Comment: When I saw your answer, I almost threw mine away. They're very similar, the difference is you're throwing an error, while I'm returning the instance if there is one already.

Comment: +1, but it seems to me that what's missing from both your answers is some kind of `Client.getSingletonInstance()` method which creates and returns a new instance if none has been created, and returns the existing one otherwise. Isn't that basically the point of the singleton pattern? To have the user of the class use a static method to get their instance rather than call new, yet always get the same instance?

Comment: @MarkAmery: Well, that's what bfavaretto's answer does right but with the constructor? It all depends on if you want to allow calling the constructor more than once or not.

Comment: @elclanrs See my answer for what I mean. Basically, it's shifting what the user of the class would do using 'new' in bfavaretto's case to being done via something simulating a 'static method' instead, and throwing an error if the user of the class tries to instantiate it a second time with `new`. I think this keeps the best of both your approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
var initialized = false;

function initialize() {
    if (!initialized) {
        window.client = new Client();
        initialized = true;
    }
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't. In strongly-typed languages, singletons are made by having private constructors and exposing a static property that contains the only instance of the class. The only thing you may do to prevent instantiating a second time is to throw exceptions but that is even poorer design. You may however delay instantiating your object:

```
// A wrapper function
var client = (function () {
    var client = function() {
       // Actual class
    }
    var instance = null;
    // Property to return the instance
    Object.defineProperty("instance", {
        get: function () {
            if (!instance) { instance = new client(); }
            return instance;
        }
    }
   return client;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite pattern for singleton instance, it is simple and straightforward:

```
var mySingleton = new function() {
    // ...
}
```

So you can do:

```
var myClient = new function() {
    this.director = null;
    this.initialize = function() {
        // Setup the rendering engine
        this.director = new lime.Director(
            document.body, 
            window.innerWidth, 
            window.innerHeight
        );
    }
}

window.onload = myClient.initialize();
```

Source: [Singleton pattern by Alexander Podgorny](http://dot-js.blogspot.com/2013/06/blog-post.html)